# Calling lambda function directly

Tags: function, lambda, scheme

```
(define a1 (list 1 2 3 4))
(define a2 (list + - * /))
(define a3 (list 5 6 7 8))
(map (lambda (x y z) (y x z))
a1 a2 a3)
```

How do I call this lambda function directly without using map?
All it does is switching y and x, so that (1 + 5) becomes (+ 1 5)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Scheme (R5RS) , sorry for not making it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can write you map expression without switching the arguments:

```
(map (lambda (x y z) (x y z)) a2 a1 a3) ; ==> (6 -4 21 1/2)
```

Notice I have just switched the order of the arguments to map.
You can call a lambda by wrapping it in parenthesis and adding arguments.. eg.

```
((lambda (op1 proc op2) (proc op1 op2)) + 2 3) ; ==> 5
```

The `map` function is just a way of doing that with every element of the different lists. You can get the same result without using lambda if you know the length of the lists:

```
(list ((car a2) (car a1) (car a3))
      ((cadr a2) (cadr a1) (cadr a3))
      ((caddr a2) (caddr a1) (caddr a3))
      ((cadddr a2) (cadddr a1) (cadddr a3))) ; ==> (6 -4 21 1/2)
```

Since every element of `a2` is a procedure wrapping it and arguments in parenthesis applies the procedure.

A lambda form `(lambda (arg ...) body ...)` gets evaluated and turns into a procedure object. When you define named procedure the same happens but the name gets bound to that procedure object. In fact. there is not difference between these 3 versions:

```
;; version 1 using syntactic sugar define for procedures
(define (test x) (* x x))
(test 10) ;==> 100

;; version 2 defineing a variable to a procedure
(define test (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(test 10) ;==> 100

;; version 3 using the procdure directly
((lambda (x) (* x x)) 10) ; ==> 100
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, to call a function in Scheme you write `(f args)`, where `f` is the function and `args` is the list of arguments. This isn't any different whether `f` is a named function or a lambda. So to call your lambda function directly, you'd write:

```
;( -----------f------------ args- )
 ( (lambda (x y z) (y x z)) 1 + 2 )
```

Of course that's just a rather convoluted way of writing `(+ 1 2)`, but there you go.

Comment: How do I do this by using the defines I've set up?
Since they're in a list, I'd have to use map, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @JohnNG Are you asking how to do what `map` does without using `map`? If so, you'd need to define your own recursive function (or alternatively a named `let`) or use a fold instead (unless you have the same objection to that as to `map`).

Comment: You'd start with somethign like `((lambda (x y z) (y x z)) (car a1) (car a2) (car a3))`.